# MS Sync Framework Error:'.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, microsoft-sync-framework

I am trying to sync a table with xml field in it using MS Sync Framework 2.1 and I am getting this error `'.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character.`

Does anyone know how to skip rows with invalid xml data during sync?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the error is being raised in the ApplyChangeFailed event, then you simply skip it.

or you can intercept the xml data in the ChangesSelected event, validate the xml, then remove them from the change dataset if invalid